# Barra de Carregamento

Tags: javascript, ajax

Olá, como que faço para criar uma barra de carregamento não precisar ser um progress bar, até receber o retorno de uma função.

```
      $.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
                console.log(response);
}
```

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Como usar Progressbar com Ajax e PHP?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/107151/como-usar-progressbar-com-ajax-e-php)

Comment: @NetinhoSantos Verifiquei essa pergunta, mas infelizmente o caso é diferente, nessa pergunta eles falam de upload e com php, no meu caso estou usando o javascript puro, e não quero pegar em si o "tempo", quero só mostra para usuário que a requisição até obter a reposta do servidor da cielo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utilize a biblioteca [JqueryBlockUI](http://malsup.com/jquery/block/#overview), veja abaixo a implementação.

```js
$(document).ajaxStart($.blockUI({
  message: ' Carregando... '
})).ajaxStop($.unblockUI);
$.ajax({
  url: "https://httpbin.org/get",
  success: function() {
    console.log("Ajax Concluído")
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.blockUI/2.70/jquery.blockUI.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Utilize ***beforeSend***:

```
$.ajax({
      url: "sua url",
      beforeSend: function() {
        $('elemento').addClass('.show');//ativa o elemento de carregamento no html
      }
    })
      .done(function( data ) {
          $('elemento').addClass('.hidden');//remove o elemento de carregamento no html
      });
```